# Create a column name in a cross table using data from the column in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am trying to create a cross table with columns using custom expressions. I have columns that aggregate as YTD, Last year years to date, current month, last month, and two months prior. I would like to have the month-year [October 2018] instead of just a static [Current month]. Is that even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible?  Yes.
Obvious and well-designed?  Not that I know of.

The workaround I put together involves running a script when you open the analytic (which, for me, involves HTML, javascript, and a hidden button).  If you're new to Spotfire, this may be a bit convoluted -- you can still use the same IronPython script, but you may want to throw it on a visible button, and just have your users click it to "refresh" the column names.

I then make a string Property named udMonthName, and the IronPython script is as follows:

```
import datetime
mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
Document.Properties['udMonthName'] =  mydate.strftime("%B %Y")
```

You can then put the property itself as the column name:

```
... as [${udMonthName}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a long way to go before I can implement your suggestions. Will keep you posted!

Comment: I imagine you could also accomplish the same thing using TERR and have the document property update automatically. Unfortunately, TERR returns reals to Spotfire instead of dates as far as I can tell.